# Linq Group by Month, Aggregate count

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I would like to know how to solve my problem with Linq by grouping by month with aggregate count.

Below is my sample data:

```
Code     CodeName   Color       Month
11111     One       Red          1
11111     One       Red          1
11111     One       Red          2
22222     Two       Green        2
33333     Three     Yellow       3
44444     Four      Blue         4
44444     Four      Blue         4
55555     Five      White        5
```

I would like to see the results like this:

```
Code      CodeName     Color     Count(Mont1)   Month2     Month3    Month4    Month5
11111       one        red           2            1          0         0         0
22222       two        Green         0            1          0         0         0
33333       three      Yellow        0            0          1         0         0
44444       four       Blue          0            0          0         2         0
55555       five       White         0            0          0         0         1
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Look for LINQ + pivot and find out that there is no silver bullet. This has been asked in many ways before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that produces your desired result

The core of it is this:

- Group the elements by their `Code` properties
- Group the elements in each grouping by their `Color` properties
- Process each grouping, creating the result where each `MonthX` property is set to the count of the objects within the inner grouping (items by code by color) having the given month identifier

This handles specifically the 5 month values provided in the question, you can either split out all month values that you like into their own properties on your result object or build that out to a dictionary of month index versus count if other values are required.

```
public enum Number
{
    One = 11111,
    Two = 22222,
    Three = 33333,
    Four = 44444,
    Five = 55555
}

public class Data
{
    public Number Code { get; set; }
    public string CodeName { get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(Number), Code); } }
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Number Code { get; set; }
    public string CodeName { get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(Number), Code); } }
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }
    public int Month1 { get; set; }
    public int Month2 { get; set; }
    public int Month3 { get; set; }
    public int Month4 { get; set; }
    public int Month5 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new Data[]
        {
            new Data{Code = Number.One, Color = ConsoleColor.Red, Month = 1},
            new Data{Code = Number.One, Color = ConsoleColor.Red, Month = 1},
            new Data{Code = Number.One, Color = ConsoleColor.Red, Month = 2},
            new Data{Code = Number.Two, Color = ConsoleColor.Green, Month = 2},
            new Data{Code = Number.Three, Color = ConsoleColor.Yellow, Month = 3},
            new Data{Code = Number.Four, Color = ConsoleColor.Blue, Month = 4},
            new Data{Code = Number.Four, Color = ConsoleColor.Blue, Month = 4},
            new Data{Code = Number.Five, Color = ConsoleColor.White, Month = 5},
        };

        var results = items.GroupBy(x => x.Code).Select(
            x => x.GroupBy(y => y.Color)
                  .Select(z => new Result
                  {
                      Code = x.Key,
                      Color = z.Key,
                      Month1 = z.Count(q => q.Month == 1),
                      Month2 = z.Count(q => q.Month == 2),
                      Month3 = z.Count(q => q.Month == 3),
                      Month4 = z.Count(q => q.Month == 4),
                      Month5 = z.Count(q => q.Month == 5),
                  }).ToList());

        var resultList = results.ToList();
    }
}
```